# Is there a MIME type assigned to a simple Unix configuration file type?

Tags: configuration, mime-type

When I check with `file <unix>.conf`, it tells me ASCII text (`text/plain` as an actual MIME type), which is correct, but I was wondering whether there was a MIME type defined for a simple Unix like configuration with just variable names, an equal sign, and a value:

```
path=/usr/share/my-prog
temp=/tmp
...
```

Maybe something to do with having a shell script (since loading such a file would work in a shell script too.)

I know of the [IANA list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), although I could not really find anything that matches with what I'm asking.

Comment: Mime types care about file structure, not the content in the file.

Comment: Yeah, it's `text/plain`. No other type has been defined for 'configuration' files.